# Getting error "Device doesn't support the messaging feature" in android 13

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I'm getting an Exception like `com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: Device doesn't support the messaging feature` in Android 13

It works fine on another version as well as the Android 13 emulator in Android studio, but when I connect an Android 13 physical device it throws the above error.

```
   try {
        SmsRetrieverClient mClient = SmsRetriever.getClient(this);
        Task<Void> mTask = mClient.startSmsRetriever();
        mTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("mobile", stringFromView(binding.etPhoneNumber));
                bundle.putString("setting", settingScreen);
                startActivity(OtpActivity.class, bundle);
//                Toast.makeText(mContext, "SMS Retriever starts", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        mTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For temporary work around solution
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/275036593#comment31

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).